# How to use select command by another Select result? (mysql, php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some problem.

Here's my sample tables.

```
create table Board (
readLevel   tinyint not null,
writeLevel  tinyint not null,
PRIMARY KEY (boardID) ) engine=InnoDB character set=utf8;

create table Post (
postID          int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
title           char(50) not null,
content         TEXT not null,
writeDate       date not null,
readCount       int not null,
PRIMARY KEY (postID)) engine=InnoDB character set=utf8;


create table Save_Board_Post(
boardID   char(30) not null,
postID    int not null,
FOREIGN KEY (boardID) REFERENCES Board(boardID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (postID) REFERENCES Post(postID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ) engine=InnoDB character set=utf8;
```

First table is very simple Board, and second is Post.

Third is relation table between Board and Post.

I want to use SELECT command at Post table by SELECT result from 'Save_Board_Post'.

e.g

```
select postID from Save_Board_Post where boardID= 'testBoard';
```

In this case, output result in console is...

postID

1

2

and I want to use this result for next select.

```
select * from Post where (SELECT Result);
```

How to put them?

I already use this sentence.

```
select * from Post where "select postID from Save_Board_Post where boardID= 'testBoard' ";
```

but there's no result in console.

Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from Post where PostID IN 
(select postID 
    from Save_Board_Post 
    where boardID= 'testBoard');
```

Comment: I guessed conditional sentence is must in quotation marks, not in the brackets. thanks again!

Comment: @Pororoca you could always select my answer as correct to thank me. ;).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is called a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM Post p 
WHERE p.postID IN (
    SELECT postID FROM Save_Board_Post 
    WHERE boardID = 'testboard');
```